# Commuting with a rank deficient matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a positive definite matrix $X$ of size $n \times n$ and postive semidefinte $Q$ of same size and rank $m \leq n$.

If $X$ and $Q$ commute, i.e, $XQ = QX$ is then $Q X = \alpha Q$ for some scalar $\alpha$?

For instance $m = 1$, the eigenvalue decomposition yields $Q = \lambda u u^T$ for vector $u$ and eigenvalue $\lambda$. For $Q X = \lambda u u^T X$ to be symmetric, it is $u^T X = \alpha u^T$. Can this argument be expanded to $m > 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. As a counterexample, consider the diagonal matrices
$$
X = \pmatrix{1\\&2\\&&3}, \quad Q = \pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&0}.
$$

A non-diagonal counterexample:
$$
X = \pmatrix{3&-1&-1\\-1&4&-2\\-1&-2&4}, 
\quad Q = \pmatrix{2&-1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\-1&-1&2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the example, unfortunately, I did not excluded $X$ not being diagonal as this is the uninteresting case for commuting matrices. Would that still be no for $X$ not diagonal?

Comment: Yes, it is still no. There is nothing special about diagonal matrices in this regard.

Comment: Ok, I see now that I can expand your example on 'lower diagonal block'.

Comment: @SebastianSchlecht I've added a non-diagonal counterexample in case that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. For confirmation; the $m = 1$ case still holds right?

Comment: @SebastianSchlecht Yes, it holds